# Create Delegation Certificate Transaction

Tags: cardano-cli

When building the Create Delegation Certificate Transaction with the cardano-cli, do we need to use all the Utxos of a wallet/base.address? or we can just use one Utxo only as long as it covers the fee?

from [coincashewnut](https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node/how-to-delegate-to-a-stakepool)

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
    ${tx_in} \ #all the Utxos in an address here? or just one is enough?
    --tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+${txOut} \
    --invalid-hereafter $(( ${currentSlot} + 10000)) \
    --fee ${fee} \
    --certificate-file deleg.cert \
    --out-file tx.raw
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only purpose of this transaction is to submit a delegation certificate, then the only costs will be the fee for submitting it. Any UTXO will suffice of the `--tx-in`, so long as the TX is then signed by the appropriate payment (for the fee) and staking keys (for the delegation). Once submitted, any and all UTXO's residing at the address(es) in the delegation certificate will automatically be delegated to whatever pool you've chosen - no need to manually delegate individual UTXOs.

Fun fact: you can even pay the fee for such a transaction from an address/wallet completely unassociated with the address you are delegating, so long as the Tx contains the appropriate payment signatures.